# missing the new xaml controls on VS2013

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I finished targeting my Windows Phone 8.0 project to 8.1
but the ToolBox Controls are still the same like 8.0 xaml controls

for example : the new `DatePicker` control

Then i did the following

- Tools
- Choose ToolBox Items

The **Windows Phone Silverlight Components** tab isn't showing any 8.1 Controls

But!, The **Windows and Windows Phone XAML Components** tab is showing all the new 8.1 Controls  (And they are all checked)

But why i am not seeing them in my ToolBox ?, and they don't appear in XAML code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a duplicate but it's for the same reason I explained in this other question: [targeting WP 8.0 app to WP8.1 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576644/targeting-wp-8-0-app-to-wp8-1-app)

Bottom line is you're still targeting Silverlight and not the XAML for WinRT which is where the new controls are.