# targeting WP 8.0 app to WP8.1 app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I installed Visual Studio 2013 (With Update 2)

and i was working on my Project in VS2012 for Windows Phone 8.0

And now i decided to **Upgrade** it to a Windows Phone 8.1 app

so i followed the instructions and **Targeted** the app !

and everything's done successfully , BUT! the app now is **(Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1)**

Picture:

[image: target info]

unlike other people who targeted to **(Windows Phone 8.1)** , there is a huge difference between the two types of the projects

I can't use the new XAML controls - `Windows.UI.XAML`

What can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight XAML and the new Win8.1/WinPhone8.1 XAML (aka XAML for WinRT) are two different things.
If you started your app with Silverlight you have to stick to it, or create your whole UI again with the new XAML (which as I said, it is now compatible with Win8.1)

**Edit**: Found an interesting article you might want to take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229571.aspx

**Edit** See also this article: What's next for Windows Phone 8 developers ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn655121(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn655121%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)).

Comment: But my Windows Phone 8.0 app is not Silverlight , I remember i created a new project For Windows Phone 8 in VS2013

Comment: For windows phone 8 you could only use Silverlight (or C++), your app package was a xap file, right?

Comment: Right ! , so there is no way to upgrade the app to Windows Phone 8.1 with XAML?  , should i start work on the UI ?

Comment: If you really need something from the new XAML for WinRT I would... it's a matter of cost vs benefit. Do not start any new development with Silverlight ;)

Comment: See also this article: What's next for Windows Phone 8 developers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn655121(v=vs.105).aspx)